# file_get_contents() gives only last value in a for loop

Tags: php

I am trying to get content of url and save in mysql, but I can only get the last value

```
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $url = "http://something.php/$i";
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($content);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

append the $content like this

```
 $content .= file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: To explain, for those that didn't see it, the '.' before the '=' appends to the given variable whereas just using a '=' rewrites the value

Comment: Thank you sir Ganesh ji, but it didn't work for me. still getting last value only

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work for you:

```
<?php
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
$DB_NAME = 'DATABASE_NAME';
$DB_HOST = 'DATABASE_HOST';
$DB_USER = 'DATABASE_USER';
$DB_PASS = 'DATABASE_PASSWORD';

$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {

$url = "http://something.php/$i";
$content = file_get_contents($url);

$query = "INSERT INTO `urls` (`url`,`html`) VALUES ('$url', '$content');";

if ( $mysqli->query($query) ) {
    echo "A new entry has been added with the `id` of {$mysqli->insert_id}.";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem:<br />$query<br />{$mysqli->error}";
}

}
/* close our connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

**Notes:**
Make sure you create a database with the appropriate  `table` (`urls`) and `fields` (`id, url, html`)

**Create a Mysql Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE `urls` (
`id`  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`url`  varchar(80) NOT NULL ,
`html`  varchar(50000) NOT NULL 
)
;
```

Comment: HI Tuga, @Tuga  I tried this to. and getting only the last value of the loop

Comment: Alter your database and set the `id` field to `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: This seems like a very sensible solution (it expands on my suggestion #1). Should work.

Comment: @user3226210 I've updated my answer, it now includes the code you need to create a database to handle the code above, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the contents in each iteration of the loop. Depending on how you want to save things in mySQL, you need to do one of two things:

1. Write to the database inside the loop
2. Create an array of items inside the loop, then iterate over the array when you are ready to write

Example of creating array of items:

```
$contents = array();
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $url = "http://something.php/$i";
    array_push($contents, file_get_contents($url));
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($contents[$i-1]);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Now you have something you can manipulate.

Comment: Hi @Floris , I am still not getting who url value.

Comment: I just realized your loop was from 1 to 5 - `array_push` starts by populating element `0`. Made tweak to code accordingly. Is it better now? The above should result in an array `$contents[]` (note there is an `s` at the end…). `$contents[0]` should contain the response to the first `file_get_contents()` call, etc. What does `print_r($contents);` (without index) give you?

Comment: Could it be that the response to `http://something.php/1` is actually null? What happens when you remove the loop - just set `$i=1;`. Do you get the first value then? Because both my code, and @Tuga's, ought to do something useful on every iteration...